# plotly with rmarkdown on pdf

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I tried to use a plotly figure in a pdf through an rmd file. I used the simple method described in:
https://plot.ly/r/knitr/
I have the following sessionInfo:

```
> packageVersion('plotly')
[1] ‘4.9.0’
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

other attached packages:
    [1] plotly_4.9.0  ggplot2_3.2.0
```

It works fine.
When I try the same exact thing on a machine with R 3.4.4 with sessionInfo:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 16299)

other attached packages:
[1] plotly_4.9.1  ggplot2_3.2.0
```

I get the error:

```
Error: Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting latex output.
Please change the output type of this document to HTML. Alternatively, you can allow
HTML output in non-HTML formats by adding this option to the YAML front-matter of
your rmarkdown file:

  always_allow_html: yes

Note however that the HTML output will not be visible in non-HTML formats.
```

Is this an R issue? what am I missing ?

Comment: It's not an R issue. Like the error message says, plotly makes HTML-based charts—they run on javascript in a browser. That's not going to be compatible, at least by default, with a static PDF document

Comment: i understand, but plotly's own guide: https://plot.ly/r/knitr/ says it should work. and it works with me with one setup but not with the other. I am trying to figure out why.

Comment: Okay, so it would put in a png copy. What's the rest of the error message? What does "by adding this option" refer to?

Comment: edited and added the rest. this is the usual error one gets when trying to put an incompatible html elements into a pdf. You don't want to use this option, because it would just ignore the output completely. The issue here is that on the first machine, the png insert was smart and no work around was needed to include it in the pdf. In the second it wouldn't accept it and I am trying to understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting the same error running R 4.1.2 when I found that one solution was installing the webshot package and running the `webshot::install_phantomjs()` command to install phantomjs. Unfortunately, webshot was not available for R 4.1.2, so I install R 4.0.3, installed webshot and phantomjs and this finally allowed me to compile the Rmd to pdf.